# Why am I getting a "memory error" in Valgrind for this code?

Tags: c, valgrind

I am writing a code where you should replace the longest and shortest word in the sentence without actually making the string bigger/smaller.
I imagined that I could create a new string, and put text from the original string until the pointer comes to the pointer of the max word (returned from the function nadji_max) and then writes that word from the max pointer, continues copying code from the original string until it reaches the pointer to the shortest word etc etc

All the outputs are as expected, but I am getting memory errors in Valgrind.
To be honest, I cannot really understand Valgrind's output that well, but it tells me that there is a memory error on line 2, which seems odd when line 2 are my includes. I also tried using malloc for the string and setting it to "strlen(s)*sizeof(char)" and later freeing it, but that produced memory leaks instead of memory errors. Any clarification on what is causing my memory error(s) and how to possibly fix it/them? Thanks

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

char *nadji_max (char *s, int *maxvel)
{
int velicina = 0;
int max = 0;
char * maxpointer = NULL;
while (*s != '\0') {
    velicina = 0;
    while ((*s == '.' || *s == ',' || *s == '!' || *s == '?' || *s == ';' || *s == ' ') && *s != '\0') s++;
    char *temp = s;

    if (*s == '\0') break;
    while (*s != '.' && *s != ',' && *s  != '!' && *s != '?' && *s != ';' && *s != ' ') {
        if (*s == '\0') break;
        velicina++;
        s++;
    }

    if (velicina > max) {
        max = velicina;
        *maxvel = velicina;
        maxpointer = temp;
    }
}
return maxpointer;
}
char *nadji_min (char *s, int *minvel)
{
int velicina = 0;
int min = INT_MAX;
char * minpointer = NULL;
while (*s != '\0') {
    velicina = 0;
    while ((*s == '.' || *s == ',' || *s == '!' || *s == '?' || *s == ';' || *s == ' ') && *s != '\0') s++;
    char *temp = s;

    if (*s == '\0') break;
    while (*s != '.' && *s != ',' && *s  != '!' && *s != '?' && *s != ';' && *s != ' ') {
        if (*s == '\0') break;
        velicina++;
        s++;
    }

    if (velicina < min) {
        min = velicina;
        *minvel = velicina;
        minpointer = temp;
    }
}
return minpointer;
}
char *zamijeni_min_max (char *s)
{
char *pocetak = s;
int maxvel = 0, minvel = 0;
char *max = nadji_max(s, &maxvel);
char *min = nadji_min(s, &minvel);
char *pokmax = max;
char *pokmin = min;
//char *string = (char *) malloc(strlen(s) * sizeof(char));
char string [10000];
//strcpy(string, s);
char *pokstring = string;
char *pocstring = string;
while (*s != '\0') {
    while ((*s == '.' || *s == ',' || *s == '!' || *s == '?' || *s == ';' || *s == ' ') && *s != '\0') {
        *pokstring = *s;
        s++;
        pokstring++;
    }
    if (*s == '\0') break;

    if (s == max) {
        while (*pokmin != '.' && *pokmin != ',' && *pokmin  != '!' && *pokmin != '?' && *pokmin != ';' && *pokmin != ' ' && *pokmin != '\0') {
            *pokstring = *pokmin;
            pokstring++;
            pokmin++;
        }
        while (*s != '.' && *s != ',' && *s  != '!' && *s != '?' && *s != ';' && *s != ' ' && *s != '\0') s++;
        if (*s == '\0') {
            *pokstring = '\0';
            break;
        }
    } else if (s == min) {
        while (*pokmax != '.' && *pokmax != ',' && *pokmax  != '!' && *pokmax != '?' && *pokmax != ';' && *pokmax != ' ' && *pokmax != '\0') {
            *pokstring = *pokmax;
            pokstring++;
            pokmax++;
        }
        while (*s != '.' && *s != ',' && *s  != '!' && *s != '?' && *s != ';' && *s != ' ' && *s != '\0') s++;
        if (*s == '\0') {
            *pokstring = '\0';
            break;
        }

    } else {
        if (*s == '\0') break;
        *pokstring = *s;
        pokstring++;
        s++;
    }

}
return pocstring;
}
int main()
{
char recenica[] = "Ovo je primjer recenice sa dugackim, kratkim rijecima.";
printf ("'%s'", zamijeni_min_max(recenica));

}
```

Valgrind output:

```
==31760== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31760== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31760== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31760== Command: bs_test_1
==31760== Parent PID: 31759
==31760== 
==31760== Invalid read of size 1
==31760== at 0x3631247D0C: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==31760== by 0x363124F069: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==31760== by 0x400C44: main (bs_test_1.c:124)
==31760== Address 0xffeffe4d0 is on thread 1's stack
==31760== 8112 bytes below stack pointer
==31760== 
==31760== Invalid read of size 1
==31760== at 0x4A0CDB0: mempcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1517)
==31760== by 0x36312717DE: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==31760== by 0x363124806F: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==31760== by 0x363124F069: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==31760== by 0x400C44: main (bs_test_1.c:124)
==31760== Address 0xffeffe4d0 is on thread 1's stack
==31760== 8032 bytes below stack pointer
==31760== 
==31760== Invalid read of size 1
==31760== at 0x4A0CDBE: mempcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1517)
==31760== by 0x36312717DE: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==31760== by 0x363124806F: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==31760== by 0x363124F069: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==31760== by 0x400C44: main (bs_test_1.c:124)
==31760== Address 0xffeffe4d2 is on thread 1's stack
==31760== 8030 bytes below stack pointer
==31760== 
==31760== 
==31760== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31760== in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31760== total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==31760== 
==31760== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31760== 
==31760== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31760== ERROR SUMMARY: 109 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: Note: `strspn()` is a usefull function.

Answer (score 0):

In function `zamijeni_min_max()` you are returning the address of a locally defined variable, which will cease to exist after the function returns.

```
char string [10000];
//...
char *pocstring = string;
//...
return pocstring;
```

This is revealed by the compiler warning

> C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary: string

I advise you to allocate the memory with

```
char *string = malloc(10000);
```

and remember to `free` it when you have finished with it.

Comment: I tried using malloc, and the heap is freed correctly but I still get an error somewhere around here:
`s = pocetak;
 strcpy(s, string);
 free(string);
 return s;`

Here is valgrind
`Invalid read of size 1
at 0x4A08C0B: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:506)
==5385== by 0x400BFE: zamijeni_min_max (bs_test_1.c:111)
==5385== by 0x400D26: main (bs_test_1.c:126)
==5385== Address 0x4c31076 is 0 bytes after a block of size 54 alloc'd
==5385== at 0x4A05AFD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==5385== by 0x400961: zamijeni_min_max (bs_test_1.c:66)
==5385== by 0x400D26: main (bs_test_1.c:126)`

Comment: You are using the returned pointer in `printf ("'%s'", zamijeni_min_max(recenica));`. So don't `free(string)` *inside* the function, only after you have finished with it *outside* the function. Otherwise you are passing `printf` a pointer to memory which you no longer own.

Comment: Let's say I make `char *string` a global variable, put the `malloc` part inside the function, and `free(string)` after the `printf`. Why am I still getting memory errors? (I also have leaking now, still reachable type though)?